# Schedule task to close

Tags: gnome, cron, transmission

I want to schedule transmission to close at a certain time every day in Gnome Schedule task.  I figured out how to get transmission it open at 12:01am, but how do I make it close at 5:00am?

Answer (score 1):

Set the command `killall transmission-gtk` to run at 5:00am

`killall` will close all the running instances of a program you choose. You can find the name to give it in the System Monitor. For Transmission it is `transmission-gtk`.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks.  I set it to open transmission at 00:01 using the command /usr/bin/transmission-gtk (this i knew) than a new schedule for 05:00 to do pkill transmission (no need for the -gtk at the end) and it closed.